# Utf-8 character handling in katalon

Tags: katalon-studio

what is solution to handling utf_8 character in katalon newest version?
In my automatic test some test data are persian character and katalon couldn't read this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Katalon Studio Console Mode cannot display Unicode characters due to Windows CMD doesn't support UTF-8 encoding.

You can find further details in KB: https://docs.katalon.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3179464

Comment: Thank you  for reply. My purpose is not in console mode  and I'm generally wondering how katalon managed this issue?!

Comment: @Melika : It doesn't support "dotted" characters also in test execution reports.